# InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1193, "Unknown system variable 'transaction_isolation'")

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pymysql

Trying to output a dataframe into a MySQL database table from Python (version 3.6.5) using PyMySQL version 0.8.0. SQLAlchemy version 1.2.17 and the database server is 8.0.1.

The same code used to run fine until now. Any suggestion on how to resolve, is appreciated.

```
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
conn = pymysql.connect(host='xx.xx.xx.xx', user= 'user', 
       password= 'xxxxx', db='db', charset='utf8mb4', 
       cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.SSCursor)

c = conn.cursor()
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:xxxx.xx.xx.xx/db')
database.to_sql('fact_data', con=engine)
database
```

Error: InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1193, "Unknown system variable 'transaction_isolation'")

Comment: Not sure if related, but the deprecated variable name `tx_isolation` was removed in version 8.0.3: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-3.html#mysqld-8-0-3-deprecation-removal. It seems SQLAlchemy mysql dialect uses the new name, if version >= 5.7.20.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a combination of package versions that supports the newer SQL version:

pymysql - 0.9.3 
SQLAlchemy - 1.3.4